# Durandal local caching

Tags: caching, navigation, durandal-2.0

I am building a SPA using DURANDAL and Asp.Net WEB API.

I would like to retrieve a dictionary table (lookup table) and cache it on the client side.. basically have a viewmodel with a

dictionary: ko.observableArray([])

and access that in any other module when needed.

The goal is to avoid reading any of that list from the server during the application's lifetime.

Any ideas (examples are welcome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ladies and Gentlemen, the answer is simple and was staring me in the face : ARM
Modules are singletons and live for the lifetime of the application.
http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module.html

Comment: Exactly! Glad you found the solution :)